# iOS Swift: setting UIImage on UIImageview is very slow

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am facing a issue when try to set image in UIImageView. Loading from gallery / camera is fine -
imageview.image = selectedImage.

Then when I to apply filter(this does not take much time) in the image and then set the image it takes a lot of time.

```
 func convertToBlurImage(imageToBlur:UIImage) -> UIImage
 {
      let gaussianBlurFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")
      gaussianBlurFilter!.setValue(CIImage(CGImage: imageToBlur.CGImage!), forKey:kCIInputImageKey)

let initialImage = CIImage(CGImage: imageToBlur.CGImage!)

      let finalImage = gaussianBlurFilter!.outputImage
      let finalImagecontext = CIContext(options: nil)

      let finalCGImage = finalImagecontext.createCGImage(finalImage!, fromRect: initialImage.extent)
      return UIImage(CGImage: finalCGImage)}
```

but after this when I try to load this image with this like this UIImageview.image it takes a lot of time.

Also I tried with 
img.drawrect(..)
filtredimg.drawrect(..) // with blending mode destinationout

but this takes same time as imgview.image = filteredimge

Can some one help me to make this faster?